# Struct offsets differ?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Normally I would have a good smile, but its so sneaky its not even funny.
How the hell can a struct differ from one file to another?

I had a struct like this:

```
typedef struct pp_sig_s
{
          [...]
          int flags;
          size_t max;
          bool is_reversed;
        unsigned int sig[64];
          size_t byref;
          [...]
}
pp_sig_t;
```

It was defined in say "header01.h"
Some function I use is in "program01.cpp"
Declared this way

```
void PrintSig(pp_sig_t *s); // prints the content of sig[64] array in pp_sig_t for test purposes
```

Another object pp_sig_t called g_sig_1 was defined in "header02.cpp"...
This .cpp includes of course header01.h
I call the print routine this way inside it

```
PrintSig(&g_sig_1);
```

I notice the print result differs from the actual content.
Say sig contains 0xE8, then it printed 0xE800

Then, I thought, about 2 hours of investigation, it could be struct alignment.

I try it...

Declaring the struct this way in header01.h

```
#pragma push()
#pragma pack(4)
typedef struct pp_sig_s
{
          [...]
          int flags;
          size_t max;
          bool is_reversed;
    unsigned int sig[64];
          size_t byref;
          [...]
}
pp_sig_t;
#pragma pop()
```

And suddenly everything works fine...

So basically its like if in program01.cpp the struct offsets were, i would guess, different than in program02.cpp...

How the hell can a struct differs from one file to another? How can we avoid this without using pragmas? Could it be called a compiler bug (i use Intel C++ XE Composer 2013 Update 2, on linux)?

Comment: Psychic debugging: 32bit vs 64bit?

Comment: If it were data alignment you can easily verify it by printing field offsets like `printf("%d",(char *)&(g_sig_1.sig) - (char*)&g_sig_1)` to work out. Could be caused by different compile options on individual files

Comment: the compiler options are the same for each file. i use maxed out optimizations... besides that i dont find what could cause this :(

Comment: @sixlettervariables: psychic linking — the linker would not mix 32-bit and 64-bit object files.

Comment: @EarthEngine: Or just use the `offsetof()` macro, defined in `<stddef.h>`.

Comment: it's a 32 bit program, completely, compiled using -m32, and linking to 32 bit c++ stdio only

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: he did say "program01.cpp" and "program02.cpp". I assumed this meant separate programs.

Comment: What's your boundary? It seems the compiler will see fit to fill the gaps. You should maintain a consistent boundary.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that this was **caused** by an alignment pragma that was in scope when one of the files included the header, but not when the other did.

Comment: you mean like... a  push pragma not associated to a pop pragma?

Comment: @Yannick: that (`#pragma push` without `#pragma pop`) would certainly be one possibility.  I'd rate it as likely if you ever use `#pragma` to adjust packing.  Second guessing the compiler is usually counter-productive.  Another possibility is that one of the types in the `...` section of the structure before the array is of a different size in the two compilation units.  Basically, having run into this problem, you need to go over your code with a fine-tooth comb to find where you could be screwing yourself up by playing funny games depending on header include order, etc.

Comment: now you talk about it, indeed it may be that. i indeed use those pragmas at several places.

Comment: For gcc, I'd try `gcc -E` to invoke just the preprocessor, then look for all `#pragma` directives leading up to the struct definition. Hopefully there's some equivalent for the Intel compiler you're using.

Comment: For @JonathanLeffler’s theory of a type having different sizes, `bool` might be the most likely, as practices regarding this are somewhat variable, even on the same platform (There still would be a compiler option or a pragma involved, of course).